# How to Sort on row by row basis?

Tags: matrix, sorting

Say I have matrix [image: original]

how to sort on row by row basis to get:

[image: sorted]

Comment: Let `mat` be your matrix, then `Sort /@ mat`.

Comment: Hi @VLC thanks. Nice and simple, but can'd find the accept button? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort on row by row basis:

```
mat = {{1, 3, 2, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 4, 1}, {1, 2, 4, 3}};
```

[image: matrix]

```
Sort /@ mat
```

[image: sorted matrix]

Sort on column by column basis:

```
mat2 = {{4, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 4, 1}};
```

[image: matrix]

```
Transpose[Sort /@ Transpose[mat2]]
```

[image: sorted matrix]